# Parcelable generics and String

Tags: java, android, string, generics, parcelable

I wish to make a generic class Parcelable.
Seems easy enough. Using a tuple as a simple example (JUST an example, do not comment on this specific class, some of mine will come from libraries), I can extend what I have:

```
public class Pair<O1, O2> implements Serializable {
    public O1 first;
    public O2 second;
    public Pair(O1 first, O2 second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

and make this:

```
public class PPair<O1 extends Parcelable, O2 extends Parcelable> extends Pair<O1, O2>
        implements Serializable, Parcelable {
    public O1 first;
    public O2 second;
    public PPair(O1 first, O2 second){
        super(first, second);
    }
    // Parcelable stuff
    public PPair(Parcel in){
        super((O1)in.readParcelable(null), (O2)in.readParcelable(null));
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents(){
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(first, flags);
        dest.writeParcelable(second, flags);
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public PPair createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new PPair(in); 
        }
        public PPair[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PPair[size];
        }
    };
}
```

However, while I can use `PPair<Uri, Uri>`, it won't work for `PPair<String, String>`.
Someone forgot to make the String class Parcelable.

Seems ridiculous to extend String, adding simple parcelability, just so it can be used in parcelable generic classes.
Similarly, removing the `extends Parcelable` from parameters (and relying on `instanceof`, etc, inside) seems like a bad idea if anyone else is to use my classes.
Is there a better way to make the class accept both String and any Parcelable, and at least warn when used with anything else?

Comment: Seems like you could simplify your question by cutting the generics part and focusing on your issue of wanting `String` to be `Parcelable`.

Comment: @PaulBellora I've removed my previous comment, it sounded rude. No, the issue is that I am looking for the best solution in the context of all the above: generics, parcelability, and Strings. Generic classes come from libraries. I wish to pass them between Fragments, so I make them Parcelable. But frequently, they take String.

Comment: I can't believe this never got an answer. Here I am, 8 years later with the same question